# Browser doesn't show dynamically generated CSS in JSP

Tags: css, servlets, dynamically-generated

I'm writing simple web app which generates simple CSS file for user.

I've mapped servlet for writing CSS on specific tag, and depending of the user's session attributes, I use `PrintWriter` for generating CSS stylesheet.

Problem: Stylesheet doesn't have any effect. Chrone shows it was downloaded (inspect element -> network), but it doesn't have any effect on my htmlpage.

In html, CSS is defined by: `<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will happen if the response content type is (implicitly) set to something else than `text/css`. You can easily verify it in response headers section in HTTP traffic monitor.

Explicitly set it **before** writing any byte to the response body.

```
response.setContentType("text/css");
// ...
```

Comment: Thanx, that solved the problem! I totally forgot about that. :)